# Название без кавычек (от "Директор ГКУ Балашихинского ЦЗН")?

Tags: согласование

Можно ли склонять наименование учреждения ГКУ МО Балашихинский центр занятости населения. Например: Директор ГКУ Балашихинского ЦЗН?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

> Можно ли склонять наименование учреждения ГКУ МО Балашихинский центр занятости населения?

А почему без кавычек?

Кавычки нужны. Правильно так:

***Директор ГКУ МО «Балашихинский центр занятости населения»***.

Или так:

***Директор Балашихинского ЦЗН***.

Comment: А если у них в учредительных документах забито без кавычек?

Comment: На официальном сайте название этого центра  такое: _**ГКУ МО «Балашихинский центр занятости населения»**_.  См.  http://balashiha.ru/activity/sotsialnaya-sfera/sotsialnye-sluzhby/

Comment: Ну это в конкретном случае. Я так понимаю, что это только пример.

Comment: Так Екатерина-то и спрашивала об этом конкретном случае. Если будет идти речь о какой-либо другой организации -- тогда и посмотрим.

Comment: А в заголовке-то у неё было "название без кавычек". Кабы не это, я бы согласился, что спрашивала про конкретное название. А так - шут его знает надо переспросить.

Answer (score 1):

> Можно ли склонять наименование учреждения ГКУ МО Балашихинский центр занятости населения. Например: Директор ГКУ Балашихинского ЦЗН?

Нет, так нельзя. Категорически. У вас не "склонение" получилось, а изменение смысла названия.

Расшифруйте - и все поймете.
*Директор государственного казенного ***учреждения балашихинского центра*** занятости населения*.
Не "учреждение" же "центра" имеется в виду, а *учреждение, которым является ЦНЗ*.

Правильные варианты - у slava1947, оба годятся, причем в официальных бумагах предпочтительнее первый, более полный. В юридических и бухгалтерских должно быть в полном соответствии с учредительными документами (полное или сокращенное название). Кавычки - если они есть в официальном названии - опускать тоже нельзя.